# How to pull a forked package via composer

Tags: git, github, fork, composer-php

I have forked a package and have some changes within my fork, i tried to get the forked package by changing the composer.json file like this :

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "git@github.com:Yunishawash/api-guard.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
        "chrisbjr/api-guard": "~2.0"
    }
```

and like this way either

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/Yunishawash/api-guard"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
        "chrisbjr/api-guard": "~2.0"
    }
```

and i run `composer update` but it still giving me the main package, not the forked one.

any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

Do not put the .git extension at the end of your repository url and change the branch in your require to your custom branch. I guess **"~2.0"** is not your custom branch. You should also prefix your custom branch with **"dev-"**.

You can read more about that [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository).